# Twig Template Include Multiple Bodies

Tags: symfony, twig

A number of templates exist called list.html.twig, it would be desirable to include all these different list templates in a single index template.

Each list template takes the following form:

```
{% extends 'XXX::layout.html.twig' %}
{% block body %}
Stuff handle data in different ways per template.
{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}
    {{ parent() }}
    <script type="text/javascript">
        doSomethingMaybeCrudJSCode('table ZZZ');
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

The index template looks like:

```
{% extends 'XXX::layout.html.twig' %}
{% block title %}Contacts{% endblock %}

{% block body %}

{% include 'XXX:AAA:list.html.twig' with { 'data': dataA } %}
{% include 'XXX:WWW:list.html.twig' with { 'data': dataW } %}
{% include 'XXX:YYY:list.html.twig' with { 'data': dataY } %}
{% include 'XXX:ZZZ:list.html.twig' with { 'data': dataZ } %}

{% endblock %}
```

The list templates are also directly accessible via a url.

The following error is returned:

```
 Calling "parent" on a template that does not extend nor "use" another template is forbidden in XXX:AAA:list.html.twig at line 14
```

I have had a look at using use instead but still can't get it to work, how should it be used with the above example? Or is it the case I need to create a new template that each list includes as well as the index (one for the js and one for the html)? It's less desirable, if so is there a naming convention I can follow so I know which template are for inclusion only? My preference would be to have fewer template to manage

Base template is as follows:

```
<!-- app/Resources/views/base.html.twig -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
                {% block body %}{% endblock %}

        {% block javascripts %}
            <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/jquery-1.11.1.js') }}"></script>
        {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

Layout Template:

```
{# src/XX/XBundle/Resources/views/layout.html.twig #}
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}
```

Updated: The question now includes the base templates and how they are extended.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

```
{% block title %}Contacts{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
   {{ include('XXX:AAA:list.html.twig',{ 'data': dataA }) }}
   {{ include('XXX:WWW:list.html.twig',{ 'data': dataA }) }}
   {{ include('XXX:YYY:list.html.twig',{ 'data': dataA }) }}
   {{ include('XXX:ZZZ:list.html.twig',{ 'data': dataA }) }}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Still an issue with calling parent in the javscript. "Calling "parent" on a template that does not extend nor "use" another template is forbidden in"

Comment: Does your index template in which all other templates are included extends a file like :{% extends '::base.html.twig' %} ..

Comment: Yes {% extends 'XXX::layout.html.twig' %}

Comment: Can u give the name of the last parent template which is extended by other templates ..

Comment: Index and each List template extends XXX::layout.html.twig which then extends ::base.html.twig

Comment: k, then in your base.html.twig there is some mistake in blocks name either in {% block body %} or in {% block javascripts %} , since your error is "Still an issue with calling parent in the javscript." i think in base.html.twig your javascripts block's name is wrong . pls check it ..

Comment: I've updated the question with the base and layout templates and how they are being used to better clarify the problem.

Comment: If u carefully see then u are including the whole {% block body %},and {% block javascripts %} of individual list template inside the {% block body %} of your index page , and that's the problem ..

Comment: That's why I was looking at using 'use' to render only part of the template or if it's not possible to at least following a standard naming convention.

Comment: basically you have two options ,first either your index template should be plane i.e. it should not extends any other twig like 'layout.html.twig etc..' or  second individual list templates should be plane i.e. without any extension but ; since u have used both blocks {% block javascripts %} and {% block body %} in individual list templates , so i will prefer to first option i. e. make your index template without extension ..